# How to use the data type "text" in Jhipster jdl

Tags: variables, text, types, jhipster, jdl

Good Morning, pls I wish to know if it is possible to use the data type 'text' in Jhipster jdl.If Yes, pls help me.

I 've try by inserting "text" but it seems not been recognize by the Jdl

I wish to store the data as "text" by using the datatype TEXT, but the jhipster jdl doesn't recognize it

Answer (score 0):

`TEXT` does not exist in JDL field types, check the doc: https://www.jhipster.tech/jdl/entities-fields#field-types-and-validations

Depending on what you want to achieve, it could be `String` or `TextBlob`.

Comment: merci, c'est exactement se qui me fallait